# joining two select statements

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Can anyone tell me why the following won't work? It complains of a syntax error near the join key word between the two selects.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( select * from orders_products inner JOIN orders ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id  where products_id = 181) 
as A

join 

SELECT * 
FROM ( select * from orders_products INNER JOIN orders ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id  where products_id = 180) 
as B

on A.orders_id=B.orders_id
```

Basically my first `SELECT` pulls all the order info for a certain product from one table and pulls the quantity ordered from another and joins them together. The second `SELECT` does the same thing for another product.

Now, I have

```
_______A_________         _______B_________

O_ID   P_ID   Q            O_ID   P_ID   Q 

1       180   3            1       181   11

2       180   9            2       181   6

3       180   5            3       181   3
```

And, using another join I want to get

```
Q_ID   P_ID1   Q1    P_ID2    Q2

1       180    3      181     11

2       180    9      181      6

3       180    5      181      3
```

Maybe I am taking a wrong approach here. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
Here is what worked for me after pointers by RedFilter:

```
(SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT * FROM orders_products
INNER JOIN orders ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id
WHERE products_id =181) AS A
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT * FROM orders_products
INNER JOIN orders ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id
WHERE products_id =180) AS B ON A.orders_id = B.orders_id
)
UNION (
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM orders_products
INNER JOIN orders ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id
WHERE products_id =181
) AS C
RIGHT JOIN (
SELECT * 
FROM orders_products
INNER JOIN orders ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id
WHERE products_id =180
) AS D ON C.orders_id = D.orders_id
)
```

Comment: ummm all the joining looks a bit unnecessary....

Comment: Could you describe what you would like to retrieve from this query? There may be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but you have two select clauses. Do this instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * 
       FROM orders_products 
       INNER JOIN orders ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id 
       WHERE products_id = 181) AS A
JOIN ( SELECT * 
       FROM orders_products 
       INNER JOIN orders ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id
       WHERE products_id = 180) AS B

ON A.orders_id=B.orders_id
```

Update:

You could probably reduce it to something like this:

```
SELECT o.orders_id, 
       op1.products_id, 
       op1.quantity, 
       op2.products_id, 
       op2.quantity
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orders_products op1 on o.orders_id = op1.orders_id  
INNER JOIN orders_products op2 on o.orders_id = op2.orders_id  
WHERE op1.products_id = 180
AND op2.products_id = 181
```

Comment: You should double check your answer, it is exactly what the OP has posted in his question.

Comment: @maple_shaft it may look that way, but I removed `SELECT * 
FROM` after the `JOIN` clause.

Comment: and that did the trick. sorry my question was unclear at first, but while i was adding more details you guys posted the answers and this one turned out to do what i want.

Comment: you know actually, i think i need a Full Join for my objective and if i substitue 'Full Join' instead of 'join' in your original solution, i get an error. do you have any ideas on how to solve it. Basically i need to see all my orders in the results set even if an order only had one of the products in it.

Comment: @Codrguy That will do what you want, but mysql does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but here is a workaround: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/

Answer (score 12):

You should use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) if you want to combine different resultsets. Try the following:

```
(SELECT * 
 FROM ( SELECT * 
        FROM orders_products 
        INNER JOIN orders ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id  
        WHERE products_id = 181) AS A)
UNION 

(SELECT * 
 FROM ( SELECT * 
        FROM orders_products 
        INNER JOIN orders ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id 
        WHERE products_id = 180) AS B
ON A.orders_id=B.orders_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you want:

```
select * 
  from orders_products 
       INNER JOIN orders 
          ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id
 where products_id in (180, 181);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (First_query) AS ONE
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (Second_query ) AS TWO ON ONE.First_query_ID = TWO.Second_Query_ID;
```

Comment: Please add an exploration to your answer

Comment: SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT c.name AS COUNTRY_NAME              
   FROM STATS_TABLE ebs
   INNER JOIN CLASS_TABLE ebsec ON ebs.ID = ebsec.STATS_TABLE_id  AND ebs.USER_ID = ebsec.user_id
   INNER JOIN classes ec ON ebsec.class_id = ec.id
   WHERE ebs.created_at blabla
   GROUP BY es.id) AS **ea**
**LEFT OUTER JOIN**
  (SELECT es.School_id          
   FROM STATS_TABLE ebs
   INNER JOIN CLASS_TABLE ebsec ON ebs.ID = ebsec.STATS_TABLE_id AND USER_ID = ebsec.user_id
   WHERE ebs.`STATUS` IN ('COMPLETED')
     AND ebs.creted 
   GROUP BY es.id) AS **ear** ON ea.School_id = ear.School_id;