# How to merge the result of two select mysql query

Tags: mysql

my first query is

```
select GEAR,count(GEAR) 
from new_failure 
where STN_CODE = "BVH" group by(Gear);
```

and its result is

result if image is not visible

```
# GEAR  Total
SIGNAL  8
POINT   16
HASSDAC 5
,SIGNAL 1
SSDAC   1
TRACK CIRCUIT   9
UFSBI   2
DC  1
```

2nd query

```
select GEAR,count(GEAR) 
from new_failure 
where STN_CODE = "BVH"  
and MONTH(fail_time) = 4 
group by(Gear);
```

result

```
# GEAR  April
SIGNAL  3
POINT   4
HASSDAC 1
,SIGNAL 1
SSDAC   1
```

i want result in the form given in image below

[image]

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538539/join-two-select-statement-results

Comment: select t1.Gear, t1.[This],COALESCE(t2.[April],0) AS [ April] from (select GEAR,count(GEAR) as "This" from new_failure where STN_CODE = "BVH" group by(Gear)) t1
LEFT JOIN (select GEAR,count(GEAR) as "April" from new_failure where STN_CODE = "BVH"  and MONTH(fail_time) = 4 group by(Gear)) t2 on (t1.Gear = t2.Gear);


my query looks something like this but getting error at t1.[this ] "[" is not valid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use either LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN or JOIN depending on what you are aiming to get,

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM ( select GEAR,count(GEAR) 
       from new_failure 
       where STN_CODE = "BVH" group by(Gear) AS A
JOIN ( select GEAR,count(GEAR) 
       from new_failure 
       where STN_CODE = "BVH"  
       and MONTH(fail_time) = 4 AS B
ON A.orders_id=B.orders_id
```

or you can refer to this link for a similar question
[joining two select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035901/joining-two-select-statements)

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily overcomplicated as both queries select data from the same table and group by the same field. The only difference is what to count, which can be done via conditional counting. A single pass on the table, no joins.